# Is it possible to install MySql 5.1.69 on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: mysql

I need this MySql version running in my local enviroment, but couldn't find a way to install it so far.

Is it possible?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because if it isn't part of your distribution you can always download legacy versions from the [source](http://downloads.mysql.com/archives/community/)

Comment: Well that's the part I don't know how to do it, this place is for server questions right? I don't see a question that fit better than switching from MySql server version.

Comment: Why do you want an ancient version of MySQL?

Comment: @MichaelHampton because software requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mysql-server-5.1 package was in older versions of Ubuntu, but doesn't appear to be in 14.04. Version 5.1.73 is [downloadable from MySQL's website](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.1.html#downloads)

Comment: I tried that but I'm getting : dpkg: error processing archive mysql-server_5.1.73-2_amd64.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/sbin/mysqld', which is also in package mysql-server-core-5.5 5.5.38-0ubuntu0.14.04.1

Comment: Remove `mysql-server` first.

Comment: I'm accepting you'r answer, I had to do some cleanup and run mysql_upgrade and install mysql_client as well but in the end it worked, I'm on 5.1 now. Thanks